# Read xlsx file on C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, console

I want to read xlsx elements and print them 4 by 4 till all element are printed but i have a problem  because it prints me all elements of the file. Any idea how to print them 4 by 4

```
        // Open the Excel file.
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\Book2.xlsx"));

        // Get the first worksheet.
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

        // Get the range of cells which has data.
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        // Get an object array of all of the cells in the worksheet with their values.
        object[,] valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(
                    Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);




        for (int row = 1; row <= xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; ++col)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(valueArray[row, col].ToString());
            }
            int y = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count / 4;

              for() {

                Console.WriteLine("4 addresat e para u printuan");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop until you get to the end of columns/tows collection. Loop 1 through 4 (or 0 to 3)...

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 4; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= x4; ++col)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(valueArray[row, col].ToString());
    }
}
```